# Trouble with XML requests and google chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, xml, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make an XML request inside the content.js file of a chrome extension I am making. I'm having trouble, however, making the request, and adding the appropriate event listeners. In the current configuration, the open after the listeners, the console says my request needs to be open before being sent, although you'll note that the send method is only called in the callback function when the request has been loaded. In the case that I put the open before the event listeners, the console says that the request has been aborted. If there is a better way of requesting and parsing XML data within a google chrome extension application, I would appreciate any advice. I've left the link in so you can see what type of XML data I'm dealing with.

```
var l = "https://video.google.com/timedtext?lang=en&v=5MgBikgcWnY";

function addScript () {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#related').prepend('<div id="script-box" class="col s12"></div>');
        $('#script-box').append('<h3 id="script-title">Quote</h3>');


        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();



        xhr.addEventListener("progress", console.log("The download is still in progress"));
        xhr.addEventListener("abort", console.log("This process has been aborted"));
        xhr.addEventListener("load", parseXML(xhr));
        xhr.addEventListener("error", console.log("An error has ocurred."));

        xhr.open('get', l, true);

    });
}

function parseXML(r) {
    r.send();
    var result = r.responseText;
    console.log(result);
}
```

Comment: Modern Chrome doesn't allow cross-origin requests in a content script so you need to do it in the background script as shown in the [official CORB explainer](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/extension-content-script-fetches) (see an example in section 2).

Comment: You are calling `parseXML` before even opening the request. In your line `xhr.addEventListener("load", parseXML(xhr));` you are calling `parseXML` and passing the `xhr` object, which hasn't been opened yet.